# Divide table into groups of 5000 based on rank

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with three columns `Customer_ID`, `Rank`, `Age` and 25000 records.

I want to do the `avg(Age)` based on `Rank` column by group of 5000 customers. So, the final output will have 5 rows.

I want an output like

```
AvgAge  TileCount
-----------------
12           5000
24           5000
11           5000
14           5000
19           5000
```

Comment: I tried ntile but it gives me a different output.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: I am using sql server.

Comment: What is the need for the use of the 5000 records?  is it just a sample size?  Can you post your usage of ntile and explain what about it did not work?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use `Window function` to create the group

```
SELECT Avg(age) As AvgAge,
       '5000' As Tilecount
FROM  (SELECT ( ( Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY Rank ) - 1 ) / 5000 ) + 1 Group_Id,
              *
       FROM   tablename) a
GROUP  BY Group_Id
```

Comment: Downvoter please **comment** whats wrong in the answer so that i can improve